# Code to send Outlook 2003 shared calendar information to Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I've been trying to cobble together some code to send all the information in our calendar to an Excel file. I work on a multi-site shared network and the calendars are shared generally with everyone that needs access to them from a shared company mailbox.

I have found guides on how to do this from local calendars and from calendars shared between two people, but I'm struggling to get it to work on our system.

Here is the code I am using:

```
 Sub RunExportCalendarsToExcel()
    'Change the name of the conference room on the next line.  The name must match the name of the mailbox.'
    ExportCalendarToExcel "County, Family", True
End Sub

Sub ExportCalendarToExcel(strCalendarName As String, Optional bolClearWorksheet As Boolean)
    Dim olkFolder As Outlook.Folder, olkItems As Outlook.Items, olkAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem, olkRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim excApp As Object, excWkb As Object, excSht As Object, excRng As Object, lngRow As Long
    Dim arrTitle As Variant

    'Launch Excel and open the spreadsheet'
    Set excApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    excApp.Visible = True
    'Change the name and path of the spreadsheet on the next line'
    Set excWkb = excApp.Workbooks.Open("\\dom1\data\County\Wolverhampton\Home\[my username]\List.xls")
    Set excSht = excWkb.Worksheets(1)
    If bolClearWorksheet Then
        Set excRng = excSht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        lngRow = excRng.Rows.Count
        excApp.Rows(2 & ":" & lngRow).Delete
        lngRow = 2
    Else
        lngRow = excSht.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
    End If

   'Connect to and process the shared calendar'
    Set olkRecipient = Session.CreateRecipient(strCalendarName)
    Set olkFolder = Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olkRecipient, olFolderCalendar)
    datDate = InputBox("Enter the date you want to export for.", "Export Calendars to Excel", Date)
    Set olkItems = olkFolder.Items.Restrict("[Start] >= '" & Format(datDate & " 0:01am", "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "' AND [Start] < '" & Format(datDate & " 11:59pm", "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'")
    olkItems.Sort "[Start]"
    olkItems.IncludeRecurrences = True
    For Each olkAppt In olkItems
        arrTitle = Split(olkAppt.Subject, "-")
        excSht.Cells(lngRow, 1) = olkAppt.Start
        excSht.Cells(lngRow, 2) = olkAppt.End
        excSht.Cells(lngRow, 3) = strCalendarName
        excSht.Cells(lngRow, 4) = olkAppt.Organizer
        excSht.Cells(lngRow, 5) = olkAppt.Body
        lngRow = lngRow + 1
    Next

    'Save the spreadsheet and exit Excel'
    Set excRng = Nothing
    Set excSht = Nothing
    excWkb.Save
    Set excWkb = Nothing
    excApp.Quit
    Set excApp = Nothing

    'Clean-up the Outlook objects'
    Set olkFolder = Nothing
    Set olkItems = Nothing
    Set olkAppt = Nothing
End Sub
```

There are three calendars with appointments scheduled at different times throughout the day between 9AM and 5PM.

No matter what I do, I keep getting the error 'User-defined type not defined' at this line, with 'Dim olkFolder as Outlook.Folder' highlighted as if it is selected:

```
Sub ExportCalendarToExcel(strCalendarName As String, Optional bolClearWorksheet As Boolean)
Dim olkFolder As Outlook.Folder, olkItems As Outlook.Items, olkAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem, olkRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
```

I've only been writing in VBA for a few months, so please let me know if there is any other information you need that I haven't given.

Answer (score 0):

The 2003 Outlook Object Model uses MAPIFolder as the object name, not Folder - which was introduced in later versions (which are backwards compatible with usages of MAPIFolder).

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you! However I'm now having a problem getting the info to actually copy.

If I put the name of the mailbox at line 2 and run it, it runs fine but no info appears in the spreadsheet.

I tried changing it to the name of the calendar just in case, and as expected it doesn't recognise it.

There are multiple shared calendars all in the same mailbox; I know I can repeat the Export sub for each calendar, I'm just not sure how to get it to recognise the calendar or why it isn't recognising it already?

Thank you for helping a rookie out!

Comment: I've tried every combination I can think of - surely I should be able to give RunExportCalendarToExcel the name of the calendar and it should be able to follow the path? Do I need to put in the mailbox location somewhere?

Comment: It's hard to tell where it's failing because you have no error handling setup. Add On Error GoTo EH: at the beginning of ExportCalendarToExcel, and add the EH: label to the end of the procedure, with Debug.Print err..Number (or err.Description). You have to use a Recipient object in order to use GetSharedDefaultFolder, so perhaps olkRecipient is Nothing because it couldn't resolve due to an invalid name or whatever.

Comment: The error code I got back was 430 - an automation problem? One of the main issues I'm having getting info from it is that, as I'm working in Excel 2003 and the code is set up to open the spreadsheet again, its opening up two copies. As such the only way I can get the macro to run is if I make it a shared workbook - but then I can't edit the macro/see the immediate window while it runs. If I try and run it without making it shared I get error 1004 warning me that it's read only.

Comment: Hold down the Shift key when you start Excel to bypass any macros running at startup

Comment: Thank you, I have a new error code: Error number:  438
Source: VBAProject
Description: Object doesn't support this property or method
I think you might be right, that its an issue with olkRecipient?

Comment: On what line? What property or method?